# Can't able to find the bug - Binary Search using Recursion

Tags: java

```
/*for the elements which are present in the code, the code runs succesfully but for the elements which
  are not in the array list showing error in code statement no. 33*/

package recursion;

public class BinarySearch {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int array[]={1,2,5,6,7,32,38,48,75,87,98};// 11 elements
        int find=3;
        boolean ans=binarySearch(find, array, 0, array.length-1);
        if(ans==true)
            System.out.println("Number Available");
        else
            System.out.println("Number not Available");
    }

    static boolean binarySearch(int valToFind, int arr[], int start, int end)
    {
        boolean avail=false;
        if(start == end)
        {
            if(arr[start]==valToFind)
                avail=true;
            else
                avail=false;        
        }

        int mid;
        mid=findmid(arr,start,end);

        if(arr[mid]>valToFind)
            binarySearch(valToFind,arr,start,mid-1);
        else if(arr[mid]<valToFind)
            binarySearch(valToFind,arr,mid+1,end);
        else if(arr[mid]==valToFind)
            avail= true;

        return avail;
    }

    static int findmid(int arr[],int start, int end)
    {
        int mid = (start+end)/2;
        return mid;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you see? Can you include the stack trace? Indicating which line is line 33 would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you are ignoring the values returned by the recursive calls.

Another issue is that at the stopping condition - when `start == end` - you set the value you wish to return (`avail`), but then you proceed with the recursion instead of returning immediately.

This works:

```
static boolean binarySearch(int valToFind, int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    if(start == end) {
        return arr[start]==valToFind;
    }
    int mid = findmid(arr,start,end);
    if(arr[mid]>valToFind)
        return binarySearch(valToFind,arr,start,mid-1);
    else if(arr[mid]<valToFind)
        return binarySearch(valToFind,arr,mid+1,end);
    else if(arr[mid]==valToFind)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```